# make vertical scroll view shrink/expand depending on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout with 3 main elements - a layout which contains one Image view, and Vertical Scroll View, and A Horizontal Scroll view. (see XML below:)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelLayoutTitleImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/titleimage"
            android:src="@drawable/saferroadsshellharbourtitle"
            android:layout_weight="0.08" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="272dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="272dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Old_logo"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/oldlogomenu"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_report_a_hazard"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Old_logo"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/reportahazardmenu"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_report_a_hazard"
                android:id="@+id/btn_Council_Website"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/councilwebsitemenu"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Council_Website"
                android:id="@+id/btn_dob_in_a_hoon"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/dobinahoonmenu"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            >


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                 android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/facebookbutton"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
                android:id="@+id/twitter"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/scclogoold"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter"
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to do is 'pin' the top edge of the vertical scroll view to the bottom edge of the image view, and the bottom edge of the vertical scroll view to the top edge of the horizontal scroll view. So the vertical scroll view will expand and shrink depending on the screen size of the device.

Could someone please explain how this is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved through using layout_weight as well as WeightSum in the layouts. It will be responsive as to for example I got a horizontal linear layout with 2 buttons I'd set the weightSum of the horizontal layout to 2 and the buttons layout_weight to 1 this will cause a 50% 50% sharing of the layout by the buttons and it will be responsive to the dimensions of the device.

Comment: also note that once you added layout_weight to respond to weightSum you should make layout_width as 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! on a separate, but related issue - can you do the same thing for the widths of views?

Comment: ofcourse as long as layout_weight is available for the widget. Use the layout as weightSum. even layouts can have layout_weight.